# Is there tool in ArcGIS Desktop like GDAL Python script RGB2PCT which can transform 3 Band RGB rasters into 1 Band paletted rasters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am trying to change a 3 band RGB raster to a 1 band raster with ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 in the same way that gdal does with the RGB2PCT Tool. I have large scale topographic map tiles which take up a lot of disk space. I would like to reduce the volume of data by creating small good quality 1 band 8 bit rasters with a color palette. RGB2PCT does this well. But I have to use ArcGIS Desktop.

Is this possible with ArcMap 10.7.1?

Comment: Please provide more details about what functionality you seek in such a tool beyond being like RGB2PCTwhich potential answerers may be unfamiliar with.

Comment: Try RGB_to_Colormap https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm

Answer (score 3):

RGB raster can be converted into single band 8 bit image with a colormap by using the Copy Raster tool from the Raster Dataset toolset that is part of Data Management toolbox. See documentation https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm.

> **RGB_to_Colormap (Optional)**
>
> Convert an 8-bit, 3-band (RGB) raster dataset to a single-band raster
> dataset with a color map. This operation suppresses noise that is
> often found in scanned images and is ideal for screen captures,
> scanned maps, or scanned documents. This is not recommended for
> satellite or aerial imagery or thematic raster data.
>
> **NONE** —Do not convert RGB.
>
> **RGBToColormap** —Convert to color map.

The tool is available at all licensing levels.